# Validating specific string in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, match, google-sheets-api

## Situation:

Hi all! I have a Google Spreadsheet which contain two tabs ("Today" and "Current") and I want to validate the values in the cell of last row and column C in "Today" tab (such as C50 or C100, the row number may change) is it equal to the string of "ERROR". If this cell contain the string "ERROR", it will copy the data in the cell of A2:J2 from "Current" tab and replace the "ERROR" string in "Today".

## Problem:

Hence, I typed the following code and now it can get the values in "Today" but it failed to validate whether it contains "ERROR" or not. May I know what's wrong with my code? Thank you!

## Code:

```
function checkdata(){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Today');
     var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
     var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
     var data = sheet.getSheetValues(lastRow,3,1,1);
     var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName('Current');  
     var values = sheet2.getRange("A2:J2").getValues()[0];  

  if (data) {
    if (data.indexOf('#ERROR!') < 0) {
  sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues([[].concat(values)]); 
    }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### May I know what's wrong with my code?

A few  issues:

1. If you want to replace the `ERROR` string, you need to copy the data from `Current` into the row where `ERROR` is located (the last row), not the row beneath it. So:
   `sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 10).setValues([[].concat(values)]);`
2. `#ERROR!` and `ERROR` is not the same, so review your situation to decide which is the string you are looking for (if your cell content is `#ERROR!`, you can find `ERROR` within it, but not the opposite
3. `sheet.getSheetValues(lastRow,3,1,1);` will return you a 2-D value range. In order to use the method `indexOf`, you need to address a single value of this value range, e.g. `data[0][0].indexOf`
   Alternatively: Define `var data = sheet.getRange(lastRow,3,1,1).getValue();` which will directly return you the value, not the value range
4. The method [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is defined in such a way that it return `-1` if the value is not found and the position of the value (which is bigger than -1) if the value is found.
   So, you need to change `indexOf('#ERROR!') < 0` to `indexOf('#ERROR!') >= 0`

Sample:

```
function checkdata(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Today');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getSheetValues(lastRow,3,1,1);
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Current');  
  var values = sheet2.getRange("A2:J2").getValues()[0];  

  if (data) {
    if (data[0][0].indexOf('#ERROR!') >= 0) {
      sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 10).setValues([[].concat(values)]); 
    }}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I tried to amend the code according to your instruction but it showed an error message of "TypeError: data[0][0].indexOf is not a function".

Comment: Did you try the code exactly the way it is? Or did you replace `var data = sheet.getSheetValues(lastRow,3,1,1);` through `var data = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();`?

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification point:

- `getSheetValues()` returns 2 dimensional array. In this script, the if statement is always `true`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var data = sheet.getSheetValues(lastRow,3,1,1);
```

To:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
```

- `getValue()` returns an object which is not an array. For example, when the value of cell is the string value, the string value is returned. By this, I think that the if statement works.

#### References:

- [getSheetValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetvaluesstartrow,-startcolumn,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())